# Groovy: How to parse text response as xml Document

Tags: java, groovy, apache-nifi

I want to read  xml  file  from folder and   i want to   update it  and  make  new  flowfile(my  code   will be  placed in nifi  processor)   which  will  containt  this  renewated data  and i  got exception lilke this :

Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.

> at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:159)
>     at
>   javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.script.impl.GroovyScriptEngineConfigurator.eval(GroovyScriptEngineConfigurator.java:54)
>     at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript.onTrigger(ExecuteScript.java:220)
>     ... 11 common frames omitted Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content
>   is not allowed in prolog.     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:355)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:153)
>     ... 14 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
>     at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
>     at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder$parse.call(Unknown Source)     at
>   Script13.run(Script13.groovy:54)  at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:352)
>     ... 15 common frames omitted

1.**what  should  i  change?(  except  changing   doc = builder.parse(inputStream) with  doc=builder.parse(file) because i need  to  use  string  data for later processing)**

2. Another  reason  why  i can't  fulfill my task  is  that i can't make  flowfile in  which  i would  have placed  all renewated  xml data,  for  some  reason  i  got  empty flowfile  even if i use  this  doc=builder.parse(file) i means  use  config  file phisically(  File file=new  File('path')),   what  should i  change  to improve  this case.
3. if  i use  string  content, should  i  use  any  alternative  way  to get xml tag  data   except    using  NodeList(   i  mean  is  it  possible to  use  any better   use  case)?
   here is  my groovy code:

> ```
> import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
> import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
> import org.w3c.dom.Document;
> import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
> import org.w3c.dom.Node;
> import org.w3c.dom.Element;
> import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
> import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
> import java.nio.channels.Channels;
> import java.nio.channels.FileLock;
> import javax.xml.xpath.*;
> import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
> import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
> import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
> import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
> import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
> import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
> import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
>
>   File file = new File("C://Users//user//Desktop//2//conf.xml");
>         String content = '';
>
>
>
>
>         RandomAccessFile ini = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rws");
>         FileLock lock = ini.getChannel().lock();
>         BufferedReader s;
>         DocumentBuilder dBuilder = null;
>         Document doc=null;
>         String start,startDate,endDate,runAs,makeVersion,patch;
>         try {
>             String sCurrentLine;
>             s= new BufferedReader(Channels.newReader(ini.getChannel(), "UTF-8"));
>
>
>             while ((sCurrentLine = s.readLine()) != null) {
>                 content+=sCurrentLine;
>             }
>
>             DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
>             DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
>             InputStream inputStream = new    ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes());
>             doc = builder.parse(inputStream);
>             NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("localAttributes");
>             for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
>
>                 Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
>
>
>                 if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
>
>                     Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
>
>
>                     start = eElement.getElementsByTagName("start").item(0).getTextContent();
>                     startDate = eElement.getElementsByTagName("startDate").item(0).getTextContent();
>                     endDate = eElement.getElementsByTagName("endDate").item(0).getTextContent();
>                     patch = eElement.getElementsByTagName("patch").item(0).getTextContent();
>                     runAs = eElement.getElementsByTagName("runAs").item(0).getTextContent();
>                     makeVersion = eElement.getElementsByTagName("makeVersion").item(0).getTextContent();
>
>                 }
>             }
>           def flowFile1=session.create();
>             flowFile1 = session.putAttribute(flowFile1, "start", start);
>             flowFile1 = session.putAttribute(flowFile1, "startDate", startDate);
>             flowFile1 = session.putAttribute(flowFile1, "endDate", endDate);
>             flowFile1 = session.putAttribute(flowFile1, "runAs", runAs);
>             flowFile1 = session.putAttribute(flowFile1, "patch", patch);
>             flowFile1 = session.putAttribute(flowFile1, "makeVersion", makeVersion);
>
>             flowFile1 = session.putAttribute(flowFile1, "filename", "conf.xml");
>
>             Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(inputStream);
>
>
>             XPathExpression myNodeList = (XPathExpression) xPath.compile("/localAttributes");
>             Node nodeGettingChanged = (Node) myNodeList.evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODE);
>             NodeList childNodes = nodeGettingChanged.getChildNodes();
>             for (int i = 0; i != childNodes.getLength(); ++i) {
>                 Node child = childNodes.item(i);
>                 if (!(child instanceof Element))
>                     continue;
>
>                 if (child.getNodeName().equals("runAs"))
>                     child.getFirstChild().setNodeValue("false");
>
>             }
>
>
>             session.write(flowFile1, new StreamCallback() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void process(InputStream inputStream1, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
>                     TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
>
>                     try {
>                         transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
>                     } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
>                         e.printStackTrace();
>                     }
>                    DOMSource source1 = new DOMSource(xmlDocument);
>
>                     ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>                     StreamResult result = new StreamResult(bos);
>
>
>                     try {
>                         transformer.transform(source1, result);
>                     } catch (TransformerException e) {
>                         e.printStackTrace();
>                     }
>                     byte[] array = bos.toByteArray();
>                     outputStream.write(array);
>                 }
>
>             });
>
>
>         session.transfer(flowFile1,REL_SUCCESS);
>
>
>
>         } finally {
>             lock.release();
>             s.close();
>             ini.close();
>         }
>
>         try {
>             FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
>
>
>         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
>             Thread.sleep(5000);
>
>
>         } catch (Exception e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
> ```

Comment: Show your xml data please?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<service>
<localAttributes name="rs">    
<start>2017-09-07</start>    
<startDate>2017-02-02</startDate>    
<endDate>2017-03-02</endDate>    
<runAs>true</runAs>    
<patch>this is  patch</patch>    
<makeVersion>1</makeVersion>
</localAttributes>
<localAttributes name="ns">    
<start>2017-09-07</start>    
<startDate>2017-02-02</startDate>    
<endDate>2017-03-02</endDate>    
<runAs>true</runAs>    
<patch>this is  patch</patch>    
<makeVersion>1</makeVersion>
</localAttributes>
</service>